# Error when importing Flowbite JavaScript in Electron Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, tailwind-css, flowbite

I am building an Electron application with Vue, Tailwind, and Flowbite for components. However, I am encountering an issue when using Flowbite components that rely on JavaScript. I have followed the documentation and installed Flowbite in the project, importing it as follows:

src/main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

import 'flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.css';

import './assets/css/imports.css'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(initFlowbite)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

./assets/css/imports.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import url('animations.css');
@import url('fonts.css');
@import url('reset.css');
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
  ],
  darkMode: true,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'syer-primary': '#8B5FED',
        'syer-secondary': '#3F88D3',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ]
}
```

Within this setup, when I run the project, the visual aspects and CSS of the components work normally. However, components requiring JavaScript, such as a modal, do not function as expected. Interestingly, if I make a change and save the src/main.js file, triggering a Vue server reload, the Flowbite JavaScript seems to be imported, and the components work correctly.

I have attempted the following solutions to address the issue:

- Import modules separately

```
import { initFlowbite, /* other necessary modules */ } from 'flowbite';
```

- Import Flowbite JS via CDN in public/index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flowbite@latest/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>
```

- Directly import Flowbite JS in the component

```
import 'flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js';
```

- Create middleware to import Flowbite on all routes when called

```
// Sample middleware implementation
const flowbiteMiddleware = (to, from, next) => {
  import('flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js').then(() => {
    // Continue navigation
    next();
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to load Flowbite:', error);
    // Handle error and proceed with navigation
    next();
  });
};

//Vue router middleware implementation
router.beforeEach(flowbiteMiddleware);
```

*None of the above solutions have resolved the issue for me.*

Comment: This part doesn't make sense, app.use(initFlowbite). flowbite isn't vue lib and initFlowbite cannot be expected to be vue plugin and do anything good. The docs show the usage, it differs https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/vue/#data-attributes It's the same as with any non-Vue UI lib like jQuery. You need to initialize the scripts that rely on DOM when the relevant elements exist. If they are available on component mount, it's done in onMounted like above. The related problems like memory leaks can be expected with this approach

Comment: A vue-specific lib is preferred to raw jquery-ish approach any day. flowbite-vue exists, probably it suits your case

Comment: Perfect! I imported the flowbite into the component using onMounted, so it worked perfectly, thank you!